# Check if user came to app by clicking on SecondaryTile

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to know if user opened app by clicking SecondaryTile (and also which one was clicked).

Now I have OnNavigatedTo method:

```
 protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Parameter.ToString()))
     {
         //e.Parameter is not null, LiveTile was used
         //do something
     }
     else
     {
         //No of SecondaryTiles were clicked
     }
 }
```

This of course works, but only if app was previously closed. But when app was previously opened, runs in background and user click on LiveTile, then app is being shown but this method is not executed.

How can I handle this scenario?

Comment: Probably you can override OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args) method in App.xaml.cs and use args to detect source of activation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MSDN: Override the OnLaunched method to perform any general app initialization that should occur only when the user launches your app normally (for example, by tapping the app tile).

You should override or update the [OnLaunched](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.onlaunched.aspx) event to track app activation moment and analyze corresponding arguments (`app.xaml.cs` file).

In short, if you look on how `OnNavigatedTo` event is rised -- it comes from the `OnLaunched` event that checks whether `rootFrame`'s content already exists or not:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e) 
{
        ...

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }
        ...
}
```

As you may imagine in your scenario it is not true, so navigation event never happens.